# explained_variance_ratio_ in sklearn.discriminant_analysis

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use *explained_variance_ratio_* in sklearn 17.1.

In sklearn docs it is described as attribute to *LinearDiscriminantAnalysis* class.

But how to apply it?

My code is

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as lda

clf = lda(solver='eigen', shrinkage = 'auto')

clf.fit((tr_train, targ_train)
```

Basically, I was trying

```
lda.explained_variance_ratio_(tr_train)
```

But I have got

```
AttributeError: 'LinearDiscriminantAnalysis' object has no attribute 'explained_variance_ratio_'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved by :

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as lda
clf = lda(solver='eigen', shrinkage = 'auto')
clf.fit(tr_train, targ_train)
print clf.explained_variance_ratio_
```